# How to use successfully min_rank() in a pipe?

Tags: r, data-science, data-transform

I am currently working on solving exercises from R for Data Science book but I am struggling with Data transformation.
I want to create a new column in my dataframe 'temp' that ranks each 'carrier' depending of the number of 'dest' they fly to,
Is there any way to rank it using the pipe?

```
library(nycflights13)

not_cancelled <- flights %>% 
  filter(!is.na(dep_delay), !is.na(arr_delay))

temp <- not_cancelled %>%
  group_by(carrier, dest) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  mutate(count = n())%>%
  group_by(carrier, count) %>%
  summarise()
```

I tried adding min_rank() function to the pipe, the problem is that it's NOT ranking at all, it assigns 1 to all values.

```
temp <- not_cancelled %>%
  group_by(carrier, dest) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  mutate(count = n())%>%
  group_by(carrier, count) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  mutate(rank = min_rank(desc(count)))
```

[image: temp table]

Comment: You need to add `ungroup()` after your last summarize, otherwise your rank is still calculating using the "carrier" group that persists after your last aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

You get rank 1 for each carrier, beacuse your data is grouped by `carrier` and
`count.` That means every `carrier`, `count` combination is its own group and within
that group they are rank 1. You can insert `ungroup()` before your last
line, set `.groups = "drop"` in `summarise()` or use the `.by` argument
in summarise instead of the `group_by()` verb. Below I show how to use `ungroup()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

not_cancelled <-
  flights |>
  filter(!is.na(dep_delay),!is.na(arr_delay))

not_cancelled |>
  group_by(carrier, dest) |>
  summarise() |>
  mutate(count = n()) |>
  group_by(carrier, count) |>
  summarise() |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(rank = min_rank(desc(count)))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'carrier'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'carrier'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 16 × 3
#>    carrier count  rank
#>    <chr>   <int> <int>
#>  1 9E         48     2
#>  2 AA         19     7
#>  3 AS          1    14
#>  4 B6         42     4
#>  5 DL         40     5
#>  6 EV         61     1
#>  7 F9          1    14
#>  8 FL          3    12
#>  9 HA          1    14
#> 10 MQ         20     6
#> 11 OO          5     9
#> 12 UA         47     3
#> 13 US          5     9
#> 14 VX          5     9
#> 15 WN         11     8
#> 16 YV          3    12
```

Now your solution works, but it can be shortened:

```r
not_cancelled |>
  distinct(carrier, dest) |>
  count(carrier) |>
  mutate(rank = min_rank(desc(n)))
#> # A tibble: 16 × 3
#>    carrier     n  rank
#>    <chr>   <int> <int>
#>  1 9E         48     2
#>  2 AA         19     7
#>  3 AS          1    14
#>  4 B6         42     4
#>  5 DL         40     5
#>  6 EV         61     1
#>  7 F9          1    14
#>  8 FL          3    12
#>  9 HA          1    14
#> 10 MQ         20     6
#> 11 OO          5     9
#> 12 UA         47     3
#> 13 US          5     9
#> 14 VX          5     9
#> 15 WN         11     8
#> 16 YV          3    12
```